# AJAX Load on the client side workaround | Cross Origin requests error

Tags: javascript, html, xml, client-side

I am aiming to create a visual novel, "click" progression game. I am aiming to achieve that using purely HTML, CSS and JS. The game is supposed to run only on the client side from index.html in the browser.

My question is, I am hitting up some trouble with those cross origin requests and I'm trying to figure out a solution from 2 weeks now, and i have no idea how to make this happen. Error "Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource."

What i want to achieve is very simple. Instead of using something like twine engine, i would like to write native, because it will be more productive and faster for me.

**Options i tried so far:**

- JQuery Load - requires server
- Wrote a pure XML Ajax load - CORS error. (so... server)
- I started to write html into js files and load them instead, then use document.write or innerHTML to replace, but that can only get me so far and its hard to extend after 5 files.

What can i do to get this running? I know C#, but before i move to .exe is there anyway i can get this done? Will react.js work client side only and load components without CORS error? Never tried the framework, because in the tutorials i see they use a webserver.

Any ideas? Thanks beforehand!

Comment: If the app is running with file protocol, there's not much you can do to circumvent CORS. The simplest way is to store the data in .js files, though.

Comment: Just don't use AJAX. Learn React.

Comment: @ChrisG How is learning react going to help? React Native??

Comment: @ChrisG — If you're loading files with JavaScript, then you're using Ajax … it doesn't matter if you are using a Controller-View library like React or not.

Comment: I was ultimately going for electron, and should have said so in my first comment.

Comment: Electron seems like a viable option. Didnt know about this framework. However is there another way that i could just load local files like html? For example how is Twine achieving this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Will react.js work client side only and load components without CORS error?

No, because it will still be another thing that runs in the browser and is subject to the limitations imposed by the browser.

You need a server, a browser which doesn't impose those limitations, (something that sort of combines the two like Electron), to use a dirty hack like JSONP to load the files, or to wrap up all the files so they are embedded in the JS you load initially.

Comment: Electron seems like a viable option. Didnt know about this framework. However is there another way that i could just load local files like html? For example how is Twine achieving this?

Comment: Presumably Twine uses one of the techniques I mentioned in the final paragraph of my answer, but I'm not going to reverse engineer it to find out which.